# Scala - Use fold function instead headOption.map

Tags: scala

I've implemented a function that loops through a list and give me another List with the results expected.

I was using the follow method:

case class

```
case class Node(key:Int,
                children:List[Node] = Nil,
                valid:Option[Boolean] = Some(false))
```

function

```
def ranking(nodes:List[Node]): List[Score] = {

  def rankingChildren(node: Node, score: Double = 0, depth: Int = 0): Double =
    node.children.filter(n => n.valid == Some(true)).foldLeft(score)((acc, n) =>
        rankingChildren(n, acc + 1, depth + 1))

  nodes.headOption.map(node => {
    val ns = Score(node.key, rankingChildren(node)) :: ranking(nodes.tail)
    ns ::: ranking(node.children)
  }).getOrElse(Nil)

}.sortBy(s => (- s.score, + s.customer))
```

This part of code looks a little stranges because i think that i can write the same thing using a fold function instead keep calling using tail.

```
nodes.headOption.map(node => {
  val ns = Score(node.key, rankingChildren(node)) :: ranking(nodes.tail)
  ns ::: ranking(node.children)
}).getOrElse(Nil)
```

So i have started to write using fold and got stuck:

```
nodes.foldLeft(List[Score]())((acc, n) =>
  Score(n.key, rankingChildren(n)) :: acc
)
```

Only the first node is being added, children list weren't being added to result list.

Is possible to replace that headOption.map with fold?

edit1:

I got using by:

```
nodes.foldLeft(List[Score]())((acc, n) =>
  (Score(n.key, rankingChildren(n)) :: acc) ::: ranking(n.children)
)
```

The ranking() function is recursive. Is it bad compared to tail recursive? The solution that I wrote instead using headOption.map is a bad idea?

Comment: nodes.foldLeft(List[Score]())((acc, n) =>
  (Score(n.key, rankingChildren(n)) :: acc) ::: ranking(n.children)
) 

Looks more clean.. hence it is the better idea.

Comment: tailRecursive is a better approach according to me because of the Stack inplementation of the method calling

Comment: I got it write before your comment! hehe

Comment: Hehe! happens many a times !

Comment: Is possible to write the same thing using tailRecursive? I'm not asking to implement the code, just a initial suggestion.

Comment: So you're doing tree traversal? There should be some tree libraries out there where you can use their higher-order functions, so you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: I can't use any kind of lib of tree/graph implementation.

Comment: Again. I did it! Jesus, i'm getting good!! haha